# Why am I only getting one message from my SQS Queue?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

```
ReceiveMessageRequest receiveMessageRequest = new ReceiveMessageRequest(queueURL);

List<com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(receiveMessageRequest).getMessages();
```

Whenever I try and pull all of the messages from my SQS queue, the size of the 'messages' list is always 1. How do I ensure that every item in the queue is added to that list?

Any advise would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You need to supply the maximum number of messages to return. Amazon SQS never returns more messages than this value (however, fewer messages might be returned). Valid values are 1 to 10. Default is 1.

See [setMaxNumberOfMessages(Integer maxNumberOfMessages)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/sqs/model/ReceiveMessageRequest.html#setMaxNumberOfMessages-java.lang.Integer-).